# How to count occurrences of separator in string excluding those in quotes

Tags: regex, string, oracle, plsql, count

I have a file with comma separated values like this:

```
1.42104E+16,220899,1,,e-page remote auto,,,"Allied Martian Banks, P.L.C.",Moon,MN,,
1.42105E+16,637039,1,,e-page remote auto,,,Bank Of Jupiter,Europa,IO,,
```

I would like to count the number of commas excluding those in quotation marks such as "Allied Martian Banks, P.L.C.".

I know that:

```
length(i.data_record)-length(replace(i.data_record,',',''))
```

would return the number of commas, but this would count an extra comma in the 1st line compared to the 2nd when, for my purposes, they should be counted as having the same number.

Is there any quick and simple way of ignoring the commas in quotation marks?

I understand I could create a loop and start breaking the string in bits, counting them, and whenever I find a quotation mark ignore any commas until I find another quotation mark, however I would like to know if there's any simpler, more streamlined way of achieving this without resorting to loops.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eliminate the delimited content first, count afterwards:

```
regexp_count (
    regexp_replace (
        regexp_replace (
            i.data_record
          , '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)'
          , '\1\2'
        )
      , '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)'
      , '\1\2'
    )
  , ',' 
)
```

The nesting of `regexp_replace` calls is unfortunately necessary in order to handle consecutive quote-delimited fields correctly: any separating comma is consumed by the regexp pattern and thus willnot be taken into account for the subsequent match.

Oracle's regexen do not support the lookahead operator which would be the natural way to handle this situation.

Given the performance hit of regexp_... calls you might be better off to use

```
length(i.data_record) - length ( replace ( regexp_replace ( i.data_record, '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ),',','' ) )
```

***Caveat***

This solution does not handle dquotes within field values, which are usually represented as `""` or `\"`.

The former case can be handled elegantly: Instead of interpreting a `""` inside a quote-delimited field, consider the whole field content as a juxtaposition of 1 or more dquote-delimited strings that do not contain dquotes. While you wouldn't follow this route in processing the data (all dquotes would be lost), you may employ this perspective for the sake of counting:

```
regexp_count (
    regexp_replace (
        regexp_replace (
            i.data_record
          , '(^|,)("[^"]*")+(,|$)'  -- changed
          , '\1\3'                  -- changed
        )
      , '(^|,)("[^"]*")+(,|$)'   -- changed
      , '\1\3'                   -- changed
    )
  , ',' 
)
```

***Test cases***

```
-- works
select regexp_count ( regexp_replace ( regexp_replace ( '1,"data,and more so","more data,and even more so"', '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), ',' ) from dual;
select regexp_count ( regexp_replace ( regexp_replace ( '1,"data,and more so",2,"more data,and even more so"', '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), ',' ) from dual;

select regexp_count ( regexp_replace ( regexp_replace ( '1,"""data"",and more so",2,"more data,and even more so"', '(^|,)("[^"]*")+(,|$)', '\1\3' ), '(^|,)("[^"]*")+(,|$)', '\1\3' ), ',' ) from dual;

-- fails
select regexp_count ( regexp_replace ( '1,"data,and more so","more data,and even more so"', '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), ',' ) from dual;
select regexp_count ( regexp_replace ( '1,"data,and more so",2,"more data,and even more so"', '(^|,)"[^"]*"(,|$)', '\1\2' ), ',' ) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

better to use this

> REGEXP_COUNT(REGEXP_REPLACE(text,',".+",', ',,'), ',')

Comment: won't work, greedy matching consumes field-separating commas between consecutive dquote-delimited fields.

Comment: Collapsar look [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/172) some mistakes still happen...

Comment: and still there can be double quotes inside double quotes :D

Comment: I just pointed out the killer deficiency in your original approach ... (no offence,my first version failed on the same test case though for a less obvious reason).

Comment: Your current version fails on records starting with a dquote-delimited field containing commas, as your regex will never match record #1 (which is not preceded by a comma).

Comment: Arr...You're right. adding [,|^] won't help becouse we don't know to add or not the first comma :(

Comment: In fact is does help,if you adjust the replacement string: `(^|,)` (note the use of parens instead of brackets) in the pattern, `\1,` in the replacement. Still incomplete though,since a similar gadget needs to handle the last field in a record. For a complete working version (with one caveat) see my answer ;-).