# How to count everything in quotes as only one item

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split the following string:

```
a = "2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8"
```

right now what I'm using is `str(a).strip('[]').split(",")` and the output is [2147486448, 'node[082,'  '101-107]', 8] which isn't what I want, what I was expecting was[2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8]

But as you can see in the second item of the list, it also contains a ',', so what should I do to could the second item as one instead of split by the ','

I've read this post 
[[How to count occurrences of separator in string excluding those in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121571/how-to-count-occurrences-of-separator-in-string-excluding-those-in-quotes]) but still have no idea of what I should do in my case. Thanks so much for your help and feel free to delete this post if you guys think it's duplicate

Update:

Thanks @Cyphase the code works, but when I tried to read line by line from a txt file and do this to each line:

```
a = []
f = open(txt_file) 
for row in f: 
    a.append(ast.literal_eval(row))
```

A snippet of the txt file is :

```
423, 0, 0, 'default', 8, 8, 0, NULL, 1, 'sacimport', 2990, NULL, 286, 232, 0, 0, 1486, 576, -1, 98304, 'node581', 1, '476', 'batch', 4294901555, 6, 60, 1403219907, 1403219907, 1403219908, 1403223513, 0, '', '', '', '', 0

424, 0, 0, 'default', 16, 16, 0, NULL, 0, 'B35planar-2.com', 2828, NULL, 287, 130, 0, 0, 24691, 16508, 24691, 16384, 'node582', 1, '477', 'batch', 4294901554, 4, 3600, 1403219914, 1403219914, 1403219915, 1403220421, 0, '', '', '', '', 0

425, 0, 0, 'default', 2, 2, 0, NULL, 0, 'EC', 704, NULL, 288, 248, 0, 0, 1798, 702, 1798, 2147486448, 'node514', 1, '409', 'sandy-batch', 4294901553, 4, 390, 1403220027, 1403220027, 1403220027, 1403220117, 0, '', '', '', '', 0
```

It says ValueError: malformed string, but every row represents a string right?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? You have access to all items with `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`… For instance using a for loop: `for i in a: print a[i]`

Comment: This is already a list; there's no need to split it. Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry guys my bad, the raw data should be 2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8 and I'm trying to split it and store them in a list using the delimiter ","

Comment: that's not what your question says.

Comment: the line show is not valid python - please enclose the string in `"`

Comment: use `eval` (knowing that your data is safe): `a="2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8"` and then `eval(a)` will transform it into a tuple?

Comment: that'll work for this particular example, but is very prone to breakage and EXTREMELY insecure

Comment: @Enkri_, you need to put quotes around your string, and you don't need to do `str(a)`.

Comment: add the output you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ast` will fail for every line, your lines are not wrapped in quotes and you have empty lines, you have a csv file which should be parsed with the csv module, you can use `quotechar="'"`to strip the single quotes and you definitely need `skipinitialspace=True`.

```
 with open("in.txt") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

Output adding `2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8` as the last line:

```
['423', '0', '0', 'default', '8', '8', '0', 'NULL', '1', 'sacimport', '2990', 'NULL', '286', '232', '0', '0', '1486', '576', '-1', '98304', 'node581', '1', '476', 'batch', '4294901555', '6', '60', '1403219907', '1403219907', '1403219908', '1403223513', '0', '', '', '', '', '0']
[]
['424', '0', '0', 'default', '16', '16', '0', 'NULL', '0', 'B35planar-2.com', '2828', 'NULL', '287', '130', '0', '0', '24691', '16508', '24691', '16384', 'node582', '1', '477', 'batch', '4294901554', '4', '3600', '1403219914', '1403219914', '1403219915', '1403220421', '0', '', '', '', '', '0']
[]
['425', '0', '0', 'default', '2', '2', '0', 'NULL', '0', 'EC', '704', 'NULL', '288', '248', '0', '0', '1798', '702', '1798', '2147486448', 'node514', '1', '409', 'sandy-batch', '4294901553', '4', '390', '1403220027', '1403220027', '1403220027', '1403220117', '0', '', '', '', '', '0']
[]
['2147486448', 'node[082, 101-107]', '8']
```

If you don't care about having the single quotes, just use `skipinitialspace=True`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
        r = csv.reader(f, quotechar="'", skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in r:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks so much it works perfect, just one more question y did you print(row) instead of print row? Is it just your habit or there is something more to it?

Comment: @Enkri_, that's Python 3 syntax; in Python 3 `print` is a function, not a statement. In this particular case it'l happen to work the same in Python 2 and 3, but you can get `print`-as-a-function in Python 2 by putting `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your code.

Comment: @Enkri_. No worries, I was using python3 so needed parents.  Print is a function in python3 vs a statement in python 2

Answer (score 1):

use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module - it handles this kind of thing

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()`; it's a secure version of `eval()` that only evaluates Python literals:

```
>>> import ast
>>> raw = "2147486448, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8"
>>> ast.literal_eval(raw)
(2147486448L, 'node[082, 101-107]', 8)
>>>
```

Comment: but even if I do this, then I do result.strip('()').split(","), the second item still get split into two parts

Comment: @Enkri_, the result is a `tuple`; `tuple`'s don't have `.strip()`. What I put in my answer is exactly what would happen.

Comment: Thanks your code actually works! But when I tried to read line by line from a txt file and do this to each line: f = open(txt_file)
 for row in f:
   a.append(ast.literal_eval(row)) it says ValueError: malformed string, but every row represents a string right?

Comment: @Enkri_, add a sample file to your question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestion, just edited and please take a look at it

Comment: @Enkri_, does your file have blank lines every other line? if so, that's probably your problem. Also that looks like a CSV file, so take a look at the `csv` module.

Comment: The file does contain blank line, but even if I remove it I still got that error

Comment: @Enkri_, it's a CSV file; use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. create a counter. like `count = 0`
2. iterate over your list.
3. test if this current item has quotes
4. if so, iterate over the string, from the position of first ocurrence of quote, throught the second ocurrence quote. (Actually, you will have figure out what to do when there are more then two quotes in a single item, of just one quote).

Then, your answer will be assigned to your counter variable.